# How does decision tree classify tuple whose combination of attribute values is not found in the training set?

Tags: classification, cart

I'm currently trying to implement a decision tree induction algorithm (Gini index, multiway split for categorical attributes) from scratch and was not able to find any resources on how to deal with a test tuple that come with an unseen combination of attribute values.

As an example, take this decision tree I randomly found from the internet:
[image: decision tree]

Suppose I have a new test tuple with two of its attributes as: **Student**: "No" and **Income**: "Low". Starting from the root node for **Student**, I traverse along the "No" branch to the left child node of **Income**. At this point, no such branch exists for the "Low" income category at the left **Income** node, hence I'm not able to traverse further and my program returned None for its class label.

I was wondering how I should deal with such test tuple. An approach is to perform a majority voting at the **Income** node, however this might result in a low accuracy from neglecting the other attributes. Another approach is to randomly choose a branch to go along (e.g. "High" or "Medium"). Once again, this will penalize the accuracy, especially if the number of attributes is small.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: The simple solution would be to simply stop at the last node that you can reach and report the probability of yes conditioned on that node.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if that is the standard way of implementing a decision tree or if there are any other variations. If it is, would this cause a negative impact on the classification accuracy of decision trees as compared to other classifiers (e.g. neural network)?

Comment: I would certainly expect this to not be such a great thing for continuous or ordinal variables.  In your example, the lack of a student/no,income/low branch means that my solution would treat income/low as an average of income/high and income/medium, which doesn't really make sense.  I suspect that some other model that takes into account the student/yes,income/low data would be more useful, but I lack even anecdotal evidence to back up such a claim.

Comment: You're right, the solution would treat income/low as an average of income/high and income/medium. I suppose that can't be helped no matter what ML model you use (even NN would treat it the same way) because there's just no training data for such case. However, my main concern is that stopping at the income node will neglect the check/split on other attributes (i.e. **Age** and **CR**), which I imagine that other ML models (e.g. NN) would consider.

Comment: I suppose one way to get around the problem I laid out is to traverse both income/high and income/medium branches to arrive at two leaf nodes. Then compute the average probability returned by the two leaf nodes. How does that sound to you? Thanks.

Comment: "even NN would treat it the same way" This is not true, since you have income/low data (as evidenced by the existence of the student/yes,income/low branch).  The difference is that the decision tree only operates on one variable at a time.  The NN will "consider" the student/yes,income/low data for a test point with student/no,income/low

Comment: "How does that sound to you?" I would recommend just storing the conditional probabilities at each node upon tree creation (i.e. not just leaf nodes contain p(yes), but *all* nodes store a p(yes))